# DDD: one bounded context or two?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

Suppose I've built a system for my client that allow gamblers to maintain a portfolio of bets and track their gains/losses over time. 
This system supports a lot of complex domain logic - bets on different sports, rolling over wins to other bets etc.

Next my client wants to support the idea of tipsters. The tipsters do not actually gamble, instead they
create "tip sheets", which are their tips on what bets to place.  The tip sheets can be of different 
kinds - some can include tips on any bettable event, others only offer tips on horse racing, and so on.
My client wants the system to track the performance of tipsters in the same way as it tracks the performance of
gamblers, with the additional twist of being able to compare performance within and across different kinds of tipster (e.g. who is the best horse racing tipster? do they in general perform better than football tipsters?)

Now, the domain language is completely different between gamblers and tipsters, and there is the additional
categorisation of tip sheets that doesn't exist for gamblers' portfolios. This suggests these are separate bounded contexts.
However, there is a lot of shared logic as they both track performance over time.

So my questions are:

1. Are these really separate bounded contexts? I'm wary of adding categorisation to the gamblers context (feels like a slippery slope).
2. If they are distinct contexts, should I:

   - Share performance tracking logic between them (i.e. share DLLs, jars etc)? This creates a tight implementation coupling between the contexts which feels wrong.
   - Leave the performance tracking logic in the gambling bounded context, place the categorisation logic in the tipster bounder context, and have it ask the gambling context to track performance? In this case, it seems like the tipster context will send commands to the gambling context, which again feels wrong (I'm more comfortable with events).
   - Do something else...some kind of composition layer that communicates and correlates between both contexts?

### Clarification

A gambler's portfolio and a tipster's tip sheet are almost identical - the only difference is that the tip sheet can be categorised (e.g. horse racing, football etc).

Performance tracking is about measuring the profit/loss of the portfolio/tip sheet.

Comment: I think this is a simple composition vs inheritance problem. You need composition and at least 3 bounded contexts: tips, gambling, user catalog. Performance tracking would be part of the last one or it should have a dedicated BC, I am not sure, but I know only a few of DDD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably agree with Mike that Performance Tracking sounds like a Bounded Context on his own. This looks like the more evident boundary.

Betters and Tipsters might act on different aggregates of the same bounded context or different bounded contexts. I'd be inclined to choose the latter, according to what you say about the language, and about project evolution.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some clarification to my question. If we assume that perf tracking is a separate BC, then does it include the concept of creating the portfolio/tip sheet? If so how should the gambler and tipster BCs inform the perf tracking BC that a portfolio/tip sheet needs to be created? And if not, where does the creation logic reside? In a shared kernel?

Comment: A good perspective might be "who cares about this concept" (meaning who is the stakeholder)? As far as I understood, gambler and tipsters act on their portion of the system. There is a different goal for Performance Tracking hence a different model might be necessary.

Comment: There should be the lowest possible coupling between the BCs, so I would keep creation of the portfolio where it belongs: if it's something that gamblers and tipsters do id would belong to their BC. If it's something that happens in the background it might happen in the Performance Tracking BC upon asynchronous notification: "a new user started gambling!" --> "let's create a portfolio to track his performance". I wouldn't use a shared kernel here. Shared kernel is for explicit collaboration between teams.

Comment: A gambler creates his own portfolio(s); a tipster creates his own tip sheet(s). If the gambler and the tipster are each in a different BC, then where does the logic of creating a portfolio/tip sheet reside (given that they are essentially identical)?

Comment: Ok, the question is "do gamblers know they are creating a portfolio or not?" If gamblers are aware about the portfolio, then it belongs to gambling. If gamblers simply gamble and portfolio is a concept that arises elsewhere, then it belongs elsewhere. I am basically applying [GRASP Information Expert] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_Expert) here.

Comment: Thanks again - sorry to keep asking for clarification! Yes, gamblers know that they are creating portfolios, and tipsters know that they are creating tip sheets. So if portfolios belong in the gambling BC and tip sheets belong in the tipsters BC, how should be handle the huge overlap in logic between portfolios and tip sheets?

Comment: If I understood right, from _"However, there is a lot of shared logic as they both track performance over time."_ looks like the shared logic is in the performance tracking BC. Moreover, I have the feeling that the concept of BC and of "component" are overlapping in the discussion. BC have a hugely different impact depending on team size: with a single team is basically a knowledge/logic organization problem. With larger teams is a problem of effective _person-to-person_ communication, and viability of information sharing.

Comment: ...does it make any sense (I am basically betting here, since I don't know your domain enough) to manage bets and tips on separate BC and have the performance tracking receive asynchronous events (the bets, but also the outcomes)? I am missing a lot of info, but that looks like a "natural" model to me.

Comment: Thanks. I realise now that it is impossible to describe the domain in sufficient detail (in this forum) that someone can answer my question. I don't think the right answer is clear in my head yet, but I have lots of useful information that will help me figure it out. For all your efforts you get awarded the answer!

Answer (score 4):

1. If you see two clearly separate models, with only technical overlap, then I would agree that you have two BCs. However, be aware that having multiple BCs, especially when they need to communicate, can be a bit "expensive". It is much "cheaper" to employ modules, which is why you should not take the decision to have multiple BCs lightly.
2. The [blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), Part 4 (Strategic Design), Chapter 15 (Distillation), introduces the notion of a generic subdomain which fit nicely into your scenario. Performance calculations can be regarded as a generic subdomain because while they are essential to the overall functioning of your model, they can be isolated into a library which can be used by two BCs. This is a pattern for distilling your model and keeping technical concerns abstracted away. You don't need to implement complex messaging or RPC communication between BCs, just use a shared library with intention-revealing interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. What I like about this approach is that it reduces the communication between the BCs; what I didn't originally like is that the shared implementation introduces unnecessary coupling. However, thinking about it a bit more, the alternatives of introducing a performance tracking BC that the gambling BC and tipster BC use will also introduce coupling due to the amount of communication necessary between the BCs.

Comment: Just been doing some more DDD reading. What you call generic subdomain sounds more like a shared kernel i.e. performance tracking does include key domain concepts.

Comment: There are two different levels here. I see Domains and subdomains like basically partitions of the problem space, while Bounded Contexts exist in the solution space. If they match is a good thing, but in many legacy system this doesn't happen. A generic subdomain is a portion of the domain which isn't that domain-specific, thus might call for a third party solution. User profiling might be a potential generic subdomain in your scenario, and you probably rely on some framework for that.

Comment: @ZioBrando, your comment led me to some revelations about this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly a case for (at least) 2 bounded contexts (BC), the fact that they have a different domain language is the biggest clue.

If I undertand correctly, the performance tracking is a domain concept and probably it should be a BC itself. You can define interfaces for common tracking and particular tracking (for tipsters) - in a common interfaces kind of project - which will be implemented by the entities from other BCs. So the PerformanceTracking BC will not care about concrete gamblers or tipsters and the other BCs won't be coupled to a specific performance tracker.

And yes , you will need to synch the BCs and the Domain Events are exactly for that purpose. It's not exactly simple, but if done carefully it's not that complicated and you get the great benefit of loosely coupled code.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered that performance tracking could be its own BC. Interesting. However, I'm not sure that there will be much left in the gambling BC once the new BC is extracted (of course you couldn't know that given the limited description). I need to think about it a bit more, but I suspect the suggestion from @eulerfx will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that they are two different contexts and you think so too, right?

I personally would use the domain events from the gambling context to generate the performance tracking information. The code is still loosely coupled (since the logic just depends on the domain events).

You could of course create adapters in between which doesn't belong in any of those jars/dlls. I.e. something that subscribes on the domain events in context1, adapt the information and then call stuff in context2. In that way you get 100% transparency between the contexts.

Comment: Thanks. All responders agrees that it is more than one BC - makes me feel more confident in my analysis! I'm leaning towards @eulerfx answer, but need to think about it a bit more.